# Find limiting probability using markov's inequality

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$  are a sequence of random variables with $E(X_n)= \mu_n$ and $Var(X_n) = \sigma_n^2$.

If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu_n = a$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sigma_n^2 = 0$, show that $X_n {\to_p a}$, i.e. $X_n$ converges to $a$ in probability.

I was given a hint to use Markov's Inequality.

However, when I use Markov's Inequality

all I get is:

$P(X_n \ge \epsilon) \le {\mu_n \over \epsilon}$

Taking the limit on the RHS I would have $a \over \epsilon$

How do I use Markov's Inequality in this question to find the limiting probability? I know that if I find a lower and upper bound on this probability and take the limit, I can use squeeze theorem to find it. How would I go about finding a proper lower and upper bound? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Markov's inequality, let us use Chebyshev's inequality. We have that
$$
P(|X_n-a|>\varepsilon)\le\frac{\operatorname E|X_n-a|^2}{\varepsilon^2}
$$
and
\begin{align*}
\operatorname E|X_n-a|^2
&=\operatorname E|(X_n-\mu_n)+(\mu_n-a)|^2\\\
&=\operatorname E|X_n-\mu_n|^2+2(\mu_n-a)\operatorname E(X_n-\mu_n)+|\mu_n-a|^2\\
&=\sigma_n^2+|\mu_n-a|^2\to0
\end{align*}
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Chebyshev is Markov applied to the random variables $Y_n=(X_n-a)^2$.